# link_to user defined url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails application with following model organisation :

Ad :

```
class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :area
...
```

Area :

```
class Area < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :ads
...
```

What I need to do is, for each AREA :

- display all the ads related to this area
- generate this through an url named : www.mywebsite.com/**AreaName**

What I have now is :

show.html.erb :

```
<% Area.order(:name).each do |area| %>
  <li><%= link_to area.name, XXXX_path(area_id: area.id) %></li>   
<% end -%>
```

Routes.rb :

```
match 'XXXX' => 'ads#index' , :as => :XXXX
```

But I have two bad effects :

1. My XXXX is a static string, I'd like it to be dynamic for each area
2. The URL generated is www.mywebsite.com/XXXX?area_id=25 (i'd like to remove the ?area_id=25 part)

Any suggestion ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, you need slugs to use area name in url. You can use [FriendlyId](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) for that purpose.

Then you can define your route as follows,

```
get '/:area' => 'ads#index' , :as => :area
```

But be careful! You must define this route at the end of the routes file. Otherwise, other routes may not work properly.

Then you can use helper to generate URL,

```
<%= link_to area.name, area_path(area: <slug-column>) %>
```

---

Suggestion,

You should put areas under `/areas` segment. This way they won't interfere with rest of the routes.

```
get '/areas/:id' => 'ads#index' , :as => :area
```

If you have more area/ads routes, you can use nested RESTful routes,

```
resources :areas do
  resources :ads
end
```

Comment: I tried 

<li><%= link_to area.name, area_path(area_id: :slug) %></li>

with 

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged

in my model 

but I get the following error message :
No route matches {:controller=>"ads", :area_id=>:slug}

Comment: By `<slug-column>` I meant slug value, not the column name. If you have followed [these](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/tree/4.0-stable#rails-quickstart) instructions `<%= link_to area.name, area_path(area_id: area.slug) %>` should work.

Comment: the url is correctly generated thanks, but unfortunately, I'm now missing the requested parameter and get all the ads instead of the ads related to the current area (here Paris) :
Started GET "/paris" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-11 19:49:19 +0100
Processing by AdsController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"area"=>"paris"}

Comment: I workarounded it by retrieving this param directly in the controller using : params[:area_id] = Area.where(:slug => params[:area]), thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Actually, it implied lots of side effect on the underlying controller (an index action handled by thinking sphinx, which displays all alds per area). 
The root cause of your solution is that I now export the parameter 'Parameters: {"area"=>"paris"}' instead of the old 'Parameters: {"area_id"=>4}'. Is there any way to export this old param ?

Comment: Change the route to `get '/:area_id' => 'ads#index' , :as => :area` and in controller access it like `Area.find(params[:area_id])`

Comment: the behaviour is now correct but urls I get is now : http://0.0.0.0:3000/1 instead of http://0.0.0.0:3000/paris

Comment: I am a bit confused about what exactly you are trying to achieve. But, you have to pass either `id` or `slug` in the url. Since you want URL to be like  0.0.0.0:3000/paris, you will have to pass slug. Take a look at [FriendlyId Docs](http://norman.github.io/friendly_id/4.0/file.WhatsNew.html). Might help you in solving your problem.

Comment: Also, there is a railscast on this topic, http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid

Comment: I need to have  0.0.0.0:3000/paris but the underlying controller needs to get the params[:area_id] to work properly, that's where I'm stuck :-S

Comment: I saw the doc and the railcast already, but couldn't find a solution, that's why I posted this question.

Comment: I also tried to pass both of the parameters into _path helper but I get an other issue => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26939229/rails-app-friendly-id-cut-url